# how to display and dynamically update multiple wxpython static text with data from a mcp3008?

Tags: python, wxpython

i have a python program that take data from a mcp3008 and a rain water sensor. i want to display it in a gui using wxpython. This is my sensor program:

```
import spidev
from time import sleep
import os

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)

def getAdc (channel):
    if ((channel>7)or(channel<0)):
        return -1

    r = spi.xfer2([1, (8+channel) << 4, 0])

    adcOut = ((r[1]&3) << 8) + r[2]
    percent = int(round(adcOut/10.24))
    volts = ((adcOut/1023) * 5)
    if adcOut >= 0 and adcOut <= 300:
            print "--------------------------------------------------------------"
            print ("ADC Output:     {0:4d}  Percentage: {1:3}%  Voltage : {2} V".format(adcOut,percent,volts))
            print ("Rain Condition : Heavy Rain")
            sleep(5)

    elif adcOut >= 0 and adcOut <= 500:
            print "--------------------------------------------------------------"
            print ("ADC Output:     {0:4d}  Percentage: {1:3}%  Voltage : {2} V".format(adcOut,percent,volts))
            print ("Rain Condition : Moderate Rain")
            sleep(5)

    elif adcOut >= 0 and adcOut <= 700:
            print "--------------------------------------------------------------"
            print ("ADC Output:     {0:4d}  Percentage: {1:3}%  Voltage : {2} V".format(adcOut,percent,volts))
            print ("Rain Condition : Light Rain")
            sleep(5)

    else :
            print "--------------------------------------------------------------"
            print ("ADC Output:     {0:4d}  Percentage: {1:3}%  Voltage : {2} V".format(adcOut,percent,volts))
            print ("Rain Condition : No Rain")
            sleep(5)
while True:
    getAdc(0)
```

And here is my wxpython program i create to display it. Help me on how to combine the two program into one to display the data.

```
import datetime

global current_time
current_time = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%d-%m-%y    %H:%M:%S')

try:
    import wx
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError, "The wxPython module is required to run this program."

class RainSensorApp_wx(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, size = (500, 300))
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLUE)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
        font = wx.Font(20, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.ITALIC, wx.NORMAL)
        self.SetFont(font)

        self.label = wx.StaticText(self, -1, label = u'Rain Sensor Level:   {0:4d}  Percentage:     {1:3}%  Voltage:    {2} V'.format(adcOut, percent, volts))
        self.label.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLUE)
        self.label.SetForegroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        sizer.Add(self.label, (1,0), (1,2), wx.EXPAND)

        self.label = wx.StaticText(self, -1, label = u'Rain Condition:  {}'.format(rain_condition))
        self.label.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLUE)
        self.label.SetForegroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        sizer.Add(self.label, (2,0), (1,3), wx.EXPAND)

        self.label = wx.StaticText(self, -1, label = u'Time Updated: {}'.format(current_time))
        self.label.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLUE)
        self.label.SetForegroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        sizer.Add(self.label, (3,0), (1,4), wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Show(True)

    def on_timer(self):
        wx.CallLater(1000, self.on_timer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = RainSensorApp_wx(None, -1, 'Rain Sensor Monitor')
    app.Mainloop()
    getAdc(0)
```

after this i will add timer using CallLater to dynamically update multiple wxpython static text as i just learn it yesterday. I appreciate for who will help me and read my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack, as I have to emulate the spidev bit but this should be enough to get you started.
The code is documented where I think that it is important.

```
import datetime
#import spidev
from time import sleep
import os

#spi = spidev.SpiDev()
#spi.open(0,0)
#Setup some variables as I don't have spidev
global adcOut
adcOut = 200
percent = int(round(adcOut/10.24))
volts = ((adcOut/1023) * 5)
rain_condition="none"

global current_time
current_time = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%d-%m-%y    %H:%M:%S')

try:
    import wx
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError, "The wxPython module is required to run this program."

class RainSensorApp_wx(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, size = (500, 300))
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLUE)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
        font = wx.Font(20, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.ITALIC, wx.NORMAL)
        self.SetFont(font)
        self.label1 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, label = u'Rain Sensor Level:   {0:4d}  Percentage:     {1:3}%  Voltage:    {2} V'.format(adcOut, percent, volts))

        #Give the labels unique names

        self.label1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLUE)
        self.label1.SetForegroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        sizer.Add(self.label1, (1,0), (1,2), wx.EXPAND)

        self.label2 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, label = u'Rain Condition:  {}'.format(rain_condition))
        self.label2.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLUE)
        self.label2.SetForegroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        sizer.Add(self.label2, (2,0), (1,3), wx.EXPAND)

        self.label3 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, label = u'Time Updated: {}'.format(current_time))
        self.label3.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLUE)
        self.label3.SetForegroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        sizer.Add(self.label3, (3,0), (1,4), wx.EXPAND)

    #Create a timer and perform on_timer every 1000 milliseconds(change to 5000)
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.on_timer, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(1000)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Show(True)

    def on_timer(self,event):
        channel = 0
        if ((channel>7)or(channel<0)):
            return -1
    #Hack out spidev references and use globals to emulate something happening

#        r = spi.xfer2([1, (8+channel) << 4, 0])
#        adcOut = ((r[1]&3) << 8) + r[2]

        global adcOut
        adcOut = adcOut +1
        percent = int(round(adcOut/10.24))
        volts = ((adcOut/1023) * 5)
        if adcOut >= 0 and adcOut <= 300:

        # Update the screen output 

                self.label1.SetLabel("ADC Output:     {0:4d}  Percentage: {1:3}%  Voltage : {2} V".format(adcOut,percent,volts))
                self.label2.SetLabel("Rain Condition : Heavy Rain")

        elif adcOut >= 0 and adcOut <= 500:
                self.label1.SetLabel("ADC Output:     {0:4d}  Percentage: {1:3}%  Voltage : {2} V".format(adcOut,percent,volts))
                self.label2.SetLabel("Rain Condition : Moderate Rain")

        elif adcOut >= 0 and adcOut <= 700:
                self.label1.SetLabel("ADC Output:     {0:4d}  Percentage: {1:3}%  Voltage : {2} V".format(adcOut,percent,volts))
                self.label2.SetLabel("Rain Condition : Light Rain")

        else :
                self.lable1.SetLabel("ADC Output:     {0:4d}  Percentage: {1:3}%  Voltage : {2} V".format(adcOut,percent,volts))
                self.lable2.SetLabel("Rain Condition : No Rain")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Rs = wx.App()
    RainSensorApp_wx(None, -1, 'Rain Sensor Monitor')
    Rs.MainLoop()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will your solution this tuesday and give update about it after testing it. if anyone have other answer i welcome it as the more solution i get the more succesfull answer i will get.

Comment: i has try your code and it is working except that it give out (SyntaxWarning: name 'adcOut' is assigned to before global declaration) at the python 2.7.10 shell before the gui program start. I also has make minor change to the volts code to display it in two decimal places and add self.label3.SetLabel("Time Updated: {}".format(current_time) with global current_time and initialize the current_time as you forgot to update the time

Comment: As stated in the answer, "enough to get you started". It was a bit of a hack, to get around the fact that I don't have access to an "mcp3008 and a rain water sensor". As for updating the formatting and time issues, your original code didn't include them and I am not a mind reader. Other than that, you are most welcome.

Comment: I'm sorry there is no SyntaxError. It show because i put # in front of global adcOut at the timer code. But i has a question, why you put adcOut = adcOut + 1 below the 'global adcOut'.

Comment: @anubismmt That was simply to emulate a changing voltage, as I don't have a sensor. I used it to test that the "Rain Condition" changed over time. It is of no use to your code.

Comment: ok thanks. I'm confused because the mcp3008 data in bit is start from 0 to 1023 which is 1024 bit before you add 1 to the adc output. I will change and delete the add 1 to adc output.